# Igor getting crashed when trying to link Jenkins

Tags: spring-boot, spinnaker

When linking Jenkins with Spinnaker, Igor is getting crashed with bean creation exception.

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jenkinsMasters' defined in class path resource [com/netflix/spinnaker/igor/config/JenkinsConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.Map]: Factory method 'jenkinsMasters' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please post any other details of the stacktrace if they are present in the log?

Also please post the relevant configuration you've provided to igor (via igor-local.yml or spinnaker-local.yml or something similar) in order to link it to your jenkins server. Make sure to obfuscate any sensitive values.

It's hard to say without seeing more details first, but it seems likely that you've enabled jenkins but not provided the proper configuration.

This is the type of configuration you would need to provide: https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/blob/master/config/igor.yml#L5-L11

And all of those values must be specified.

Thanks,
-Matt

Comment: thank you bro! you saved my day. Jenkins details were saved in the igor.yml even when i filled it with the help of spring cloud spinnaker